# Service error with Orange SMS API

Tags: node.js, curl, orange-api

I try to use [Orange SMS api](https://developer.orange.com/apis/sms-sn/overview) but i've the following error :

```
{
    "requestError": {
        "serviceException": {
            "messageId": "SVC0001",
            "text": "A service error occurred. Error code is %1",
            "variables": "PDK_SMSW_0001"
        }
    }
}
```

I try in command line with curl, with nodejs and with restclient addons on firefox but i've always the same error.

Thank

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using CURL in command line interface, avoid some french special characters like 'é, ç, è,...'.

In my case I got this error when trying to use:

-d '{"outboundSMSMessageRequest":{"address": "tel:+227xxxxxxxx","senderAddress":"tel:+227xxxxxxxx","outboundSMSTextMessage":{"message": "Hello World ça été!"}}}'

So if this is your issue, you can use for example CURL for PHP to send those kind of SMS.

Think this can help you.

Hi Mouhamadou,
Please check your JSON format there are some missing '"', test this one below :

{"outboundSMSMessageRequest":{"address": "tel:+22177xxxxxxx", "senderAddress":"tel:+22177xxxxxxx", "outboundSMSTextMessage":{"message": "Hello World !"}}}

Comment: Hi Moctar  

Thank you for your answer so i've the same result for CURL command line interface & nodejs curlrequest module  
`code`  
 data : {  
  outboundSMSMessageRequest:{  
   address: "tel:+22177xxxxxxx",  
   senderAddress:"tel:+22177xxxxxxx",  
   outboundSMSTextMessage:{  
    message: "Hello World !"  
   }  
  }  
 }  
`code`

Comment: Hi Mouhamadou, Please check your JSON format there are some missing ' " ', test this one below :

{"outboundSMSMessageRequest":{"address": "tel:+22177xxxxxxx", "senderAddress":"tel:+22177xxxxxxx", "outboundSMSTextMessage":{"message": "Hello World !"}}}

Answer (score 0):

I was the getting the same error because my JSON request was malformed. I was receiving an error on the " when i changed the number.